# I need to define a xslt to combine couple of elements with separators for custom defined xsd types

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, exslt

I have couple of custom types which have 2, 3 or 4 childs. So wherever I get these childs I need to combine them into a single element which is the parent tag itself in the output XML. I tried but could not do due to lack of experience with xslt. Can any one help.

My input XML.

```
<PERSON>
  <ID>194</ID>
  <NAME>IKHAJA</NAME>
  <DETAILS>
     <NUMBER>100</NUMBER>
     <Description />
     <NUMBER01 />
     <NUMBER02>Test</NUMBER02>
  </DETAILS>
  <STATUS>
     <NUMBER>ACTIVE</NUMBER>
     <Description>ACTIVE</Description>
     <NUMBER01 />
     <NUMBER02>ACTIVE</NUMBER02>
  </STATUS>
  <employer>
     <ID>123456</ID>
     <FNAME>EMPLOYER F NAME</FNAME>
     <LNAME>EMPLOYER L NAME</LNAME>
  </employer>
  <PERSON_OFF>
     <TYPE>
         <NUMBER>41</NUMBER>
         <Description>AMPLIFIERS</Description>
         <NUMBER01>77</NUMBER01>
         <NUMBER02 />
     </TYPE>
     <REPORT>
         <NUMBER />
         <Description />
         <NUMBER01 />
         <NUMBER02 />
     </REPORT>
     <SERIAL>111</SERIAL>
     <ADDITIONAL_DESC>TEST</ADDITIONAL_DESC>
     <KEY>5</KEY>
     <CREATED_BY>Test Guy</CREATED_BY>
     <CREATED_ON>2013-03-13T10:03:00</CREATED_ON>
     <PERSON_OFF_ONE>
         <BULK>
            <NUMBER>98078</NUMBER>
            <Description>BULK</Description>
            <NUMBER01 />
            <NUMBER02>8563</NUMBER02>
         </BULK>
         <CHECKED>Y</CHECKED>
     </PERSON_OFF_ONE>
  </PERSON_OFF>
</PERSON>
```

And my output XML should be like this:

```
<PERSON>
   <ID>194</ID>
   <NAME>IKHAJA</NAME>
   <DETAILS>100;;;Test</DETAILS>
   <STATUS>ACTIVE;ACTIVE;;ACTIVE</STATUS>
   <employer>123456:EMPLOYER F NAME,EMPLOYER L NAME</employer>
   <PERSON_OFF>
       <TYPE>41;AMPLIFIERS;77;</TYPE>
       <REPORT>;;;</REPORT>
       <SERIAL>111</SERIAL>
       <ADDITIONAL_DESC>TEST</ADDITIONAL_DESC>
       <KEY>5</KEY>
       <CREATED_BY>Test Guy</CREATED_BY>
       <CREATED_ON>2013-03-13T10:03:00</CREATED_ON>
       <PERSON_OFF_ONE>
            <BULK>98078;BULK;;8563</BULK>
            <CHECKED>Y</CHECKED>
       </PERSON_OFF_ONE>
   </PERSON_OFF>
</PERSON>
```

If you observe here details, status, bulk etc. are my custom types which have child nodes NUMBER, Description, NUMBER01, NUMBRER02. and I need to combine them with a separator ";" if they are empty or null just I will have ";;;" in my destination column as shown in REPORT field.

Also I have some fields of employer type like employer with childs ID, FNAME and LNAME and I should combine them as ID: FNAME, LNAME as shown in employer field.

I think if I know handling one custom type, I can handle the other types easily.

Can you please help? I already spent whole day on this and I need to do this very badly ASAP.

Comment: Deepu413, Yes, there is a solution that doesn't need to know any parent-element names at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**OP's comment to the answer by JLRishe**:

> It works if I list all of my custom types but, here I have so many
>   fields that are of my custom types. Instead of listing out all those
>   like "DETAILS | STATUS | TYPE | REPORT | BULK", is there any way to
>   merge fields of these.

**This can be done easily, using the fact that all these possibly hundreds of parent elements have one of four children**.

**A minor adjustment to JLRishe's solution works with unlimited number of parent names:**

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[NUMBER|Description|NUMBER01|NUMBER02]">
            <xsl:copy>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="delimit" />
            </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[position() > 1]" mode="delimit">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(';', .)"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="employer">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="idlist" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ID" mode="idlist">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ':')" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[not(self::ID)][position() > 1]" mode="idlist">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(',', .)" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**As you see, this transformation doesn't mention at all any parent names such as DETAILS, STATUS, TYPE, REPORT, BULK, ..., etc**.

and when applied on the provided XML document, produces the wanted, correct result:

```
<PERSON>
   <ID>194</ID>
   <NAME>IKHAJA</NAME>
   <DETAILS>100;;;Test</DETAILS>
   <STATUS>ACTIVE;ACTIVE;;ACTIVE</STATUS>
   <employer>123456:EMPLOYER F NAME,EMPLOYER L NAME</employer>
   <PERSON_OFF>
      <TYPE>41;AMPLIFIERS;77;</TYPE>
      <REPORT>;;;</REPORT>
      <SERIAL>111</SERIAL>
      <ADDITIONAL_DESC>TEST</ADDITIONAL_DESC>
      <KEY>5</KEY>
      <CREATED_BY>Test Guy</CREATED_BY>
      <CREATED_ON>2013-03-13T10:03:00</CREATED_ON>
      <PERSON_OFF_ONE>
         <BULK>98078;BULK;;8563</BULK>
         <CHECKED>Y</CHECKED>
      </PERSON_OFF_ONE>
   </PERSON_OFF>
</PERSON>
```

Comment: Thanks guys Dimitre Novatchev and JLRishe for your help. The above solution works perfectly for me. This is a first post for me here and I see how helpful it is. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

Please give this a try:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="DETAILS | STATUS | TYPE | REPORT | BULK">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="delimit" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[position() > 1]" mode="delimit">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(';', .)"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="employer">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="idlist" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ID" mode="idlist">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ':')" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[not(self::ID)][position() > 1]" mode="idlist">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(',', .)" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, the result is:

```
<PERSON>
  <ID>194</ID>
  <NAME>IKHAJA</NAME>
  <DETAILS>100;;;Test</DETAILS>
  <STATUS>ACTIVE;ACTIVE;;ACTIVE</STATUS>
  <employer>123456:EMPLOYER F NAME,EMPLOYER L NAME</employer>
  <PERSON_OFF>
    <TYPE>41;AMPLIFIERS;77;</TYPE>
    <REPORT>;;;</REPORT>
    <SERIAL>111</SERIAL>
    <ADDITIONAL_DESC>TEST</ADDITIONAL_DESC>
    <KEY>5</KEY>
    <CREATED_BY>Test Guy</CREATED_BY>
    <CREATED_ON>2013-03-13T10:03:00</CREATED_ON>
    <PERSON_OFF_ONE>
      <BULK>98078;BULK;;8563</BULK>
      <CHECKED>Y</CHECKED>
    </PERSON_OFF_ONE>
  </PERSON_OFF>
</PERSON>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works if I list all of my custom types but, here I have so many fields that are of my custom types. Instead of listing out all those like "DETAILS | STATUS | TYPE | REPORT | BULK", is there any way to merge fields of these.

Comment: I don't see a good way to generalize it any further.  There's no discernable pattern regarding which elements need their children combined and which don't.  An XSLT has no awareness of your XSD (which you haven't shown us, BTW). There may be a way to have the XSLT load up your XSD separately and have the XSLT logic cross-reference that to get the types of the nodes, but that's probably more complicated than it's worth. How many other element names would you need to list using the approach that I've given?

Comment: Thanks JLRishe for your help. Slight modification to your xsl as suggested by Dimitre Novatchev works for me. You can have a look at it. I am very new to XSL and I think I got some fair idea now. BTW I have almost 50-80 types in my xsd which rely on 6 custom types.

Comment: I see. I hadn't noticed that the elements that you wanted to combine had the same sets of child elements. Silly me for not noticing, but it's helpful to point out details like that. :)